# how to get the indexed section title after searching using uisearchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

how to get the indexed section title after searching using uisearchbar
 and delegates and sql query
for example i have a table displaying all contacts with section header of firstcharacter now after tying the text on search bar only the matching list should be dipslayed with result matching section header title as first character i have tried with delegates. ` func getfirstcharacter()
    {
        firstchar.removeAll()

```
    let (resultSet, err) = SD.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) AS indexChar FROM tablename ORDER BY indexChar")

    if err == nil && resultSet.count > 0
    {
        for row in resultSet
        {
            firstchar.append((row["indexChar"]?.asString()!)!)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getsearchfirstcharacter()
{
    firstchar.removeAll()
    let (resultSet, err) = SD.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) AS indexChar FROM tablename where name like '%\(srchSearchBar.text!)%' ORDER BY indexChar")
    if err == nil && resultSet.count > 0
    {
        for row in resultSet {
            firstchar.append((row["indexChar"]?.asString()!)!)

        }
    }
}
```

just replace the query as mentioned in above and iboutlet for the searchbar and take the text entered and run query